# Simple Arithmetic Grammar with Treetop Infinitely Recursing

Tags: ruby, parsing, grammar, treetop

I'm trying to write a simple calculation grammar with Treetop. To simplify my example for this question, I'm only using variables, numbers and the `+` operator. I'd like to be able to write expressions like this:

- `A`
- `1`
- `A+B`
- `A+1`
- `A+1+B`

Here's my grammar:

```
grammar Calculation

  rule expression
    (plus / number / variable)
  end

  rule plus
    expression "+" expression
  end

  rule number
    '-'? [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?
  end

  rule variable
    [A-Za-z0-9]+
  end
end
```

When I run this, it infinitely recurses. After googling for a while, I think my problem has something to do with left-recursion, but I'm new to parsers and I don't really understand what that means. Could somebody explain why my particular example isn't working and how I can fix it?

Comment: Try this one: https://medium.com/@gvanrossum_83706/left-recursive-peg-grammars-65dab3c580e1

Comment: The treetop examples contain an arithmetic grammar, see my example at https://github.com/cjheath/treetop/blob/master/examples/lambda_calculus/arithmetic.treetop

Comment: @rici Thanks for the link! That helps illustrate the problem, and I think I see some ways that could be applied in this particular case.

Comment: @cliffordheath Thanks for the link! Is there a link available to documentation on `head` and `tail`?

Comment: head and tail are just node labels, they can be anything, but this is my idiom for list-like structures (one or more). Labels are in the normal documentation for Treetop syntax.

Comment: The original error is that the first thing `expression` tries is `plus`, and the first thing `plus` tries is `expression`, which both do without moving forward. This `left recursion` has nothing to stop it so it races away until the stack overflows. Left recursion can be ok, but you must consume something before recursing.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the left recursion, you can break up the `expression` rule into two parts like below:

```
grammar Calculation

  rule expression
    plus / symbol
  end

  rule symbol
     number / variable
   end

  rule plus
    symbol "+" expression
  end

  rule number
    '-'? [0-9]+ ('.' [0-9]+)?
  end

  rule variable
    [A-Za-z0-9]+
  end
end
```